# How to update data in MS Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

just want to ask if what is the proper way on updating data in ms access Database, because when I use this code, my data is not updated and it doesn't show any error, so the returned value of the function is FALSE.
below is my code.

```
 dim conn as new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
 Protected Function UpdateProduct(ByVal productDetails As ProductModel) As Boolean
    reopenConnection()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Product Set ProductName=@prodName, Price=@price, ProductDescription=@prodDesc, CategoryId=@catId where ProductId=@prodId;", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = productDetails.NewProductId
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = productDetails.ProductName
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = productDetails.Price
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodDesc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = productDetails.ProductDescription
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoryId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = productDetails.CategoryId
    Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0
End Function

Private Sub reopenConnection()
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
    conn.Open()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting your parameters in exactly the same order as they occur in your statement? The names of the parameters are not used, only the position.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with access is you have to commit the transactions or you never see the update in the database.  See this stackoverflow thread for the syntax.

[How to implement transaction way in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298194/how-to-implement-transaction-way-in-vb-net)

Comment: hi, drew thanks for the tip, i don't think that it always need to implement a transaction to manipulate data, below is my other update code and it is working fine.

Comment: Here is my code
Protected Function UpdateCategory(categoryDetails As CategoryModel) As Boolean
reopenConnection()

cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Category] set CategoryName = @categoryName where CategoryId = @categoryId", conn)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoryName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = categoryDetails.NewCategoryName

cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoryId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = categoryDetails.CategoryId

Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0

End Function

Comment: Then I would set a breakpoint on the updateProduct function, step into it and check the SQL syntax being executed.  It could be running successfully but not updating anything for another reason.